# what is wrong with this ref set-up?

Tags: clojure

I have the following code:

```
 (ns fwpd.core
 (:import java.util.concurrent.Executors))

 (def thread-pool
  (Executors/newFixedThreadPool
  (+ 2 (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))))

 (defn dothreads!
    [f & {thread-count :threads
            exec-count :times
          :or {thread-count 1 exec-count 1}}]
    (dotimes [t thread-count]
       (.submit thread-pool
         #(dotimes [_ exec-count] (f)))))

 (def all-users (ref {}))

 (defn new-user [id login monthly-budget]
   {:id id
    :login login
    :monthly-budget monthly-budget
    :total-expense 0})

 (defn add-new-user [login monthly-budget]
 (dosync
    (let [current-user (count @all-users)
          user (new-user (inc current-user) login monthly-budget)]
    (alter all-users assoc login user))))
```

When I load this in REPL and run with the following:

```
(dothreads! #(add-new-user (str (rand-int 500) "name") 5000) :threads 4 :times 4)
```

I see that I get users with the same id at times although the names are randomly generated and do not clash as I expect.

Where exactly am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the names you are generating with `(rand-int 500)`.
The behavior you see is present without any concurrency, it is a flaw in the way ids are assigned to existing users.
Consider this:

```
(add-new-user "a" 100)
(add-new-user "a" 100)
(add-new-user "b" 100)
(prn @all-users)

=> {"a" {:id 2, :login "a", :monthly-budget 100, :total-expense 0},
    "b" {:id 2, :login "b", :monthly-budget 100, :total-expense 0}}
```

What happened here? We created user "a" when there was nothing in all-users, so "a" gets id 1. Then we created ANOTHER user "a" which will get id 2, but when you add the new "a" to the map, it replaces the old "a"... so now there is one "a" with id 2. Now we add "b", there is 1 user in all-users, so it will get id 2... the same as "a"!!!

When you use `(rand-int 500)` there is a chance that you will get back the same number. You can see the effect by using `(rand-int 5)` or 50 or 500000. Why not use the id as the key instead?

```
(defn add-new-user [login monthly-budget]
  (dosync
    (let [current-user (count @all-users)
          id (inc current-user)
          user (new-user id login monthly-budget)]
      (alter all-users assoc id user))))

(dotimes [i 10]
  (prn "START")
  (dothreads! #(add-new-user (str (rand-int 10) "name") 5000) :threads 4 :times 4)
  (Thread/sleep 1000)
  (prn "COUNT" (count @all-users))
  (if (apply distinct? (map :id (vals @all-users)))
    (prn "Distinct ids")
    (prn "*** NOT distinct ***" (sort (map :id (vals @all-users))))))

=>
"START"
"COUNT" 16
"Distinct ids"
"START"
"COUNT" 32
"Distinct ids"
...
```

Also keep in mind that usually names do not have to be unique, but ids do. So using name as a key when you have an id is a hint something is wrong.

Comment: I suspected this too and thanks for confirming and explaining it. Overall count of users actually is less when there are clashing id's as you illustrated, which should have been my clue.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no guarantee that the value you get in  `@all-users` is consistent with the value of `all-users` in the `(alter all-users ...)` call, even within a dosync transaction. You should probably move the whole count-and-create algorithm within the alter statement.

Also, since you're only dealing with a single mutable entity, you probably should use an `atom` with `swap!`.